# How are runtime errors handled in embedded C?

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

Like a 'Divide by 0' error of variables in C.

```
int x = 0;
int y;
y = 12/x;
```

Comment: The question is not clear. It is overly broad (runtime errors are many!).

Comment: It depends on the embedded system your erroneous program is running on.  It varies from system to system.  The results are unlikely to be good in any of them, though.

Comment: Seems reasonably clear to me - certainly answerable  - I have an answer ready to go.  Wish SO would allow posting answers in progress :-( - frustrating typing for nothing.  Anyway, the short version :  C does not define runtime error handling, the execution environment may provide exception handlers for hardware detected issues such as div-by-zero, bad alignment, invalid address etc where supported.  Typically in embedded systems you are responsible for providing a suitable handler, the default often being merely an infinite-loop waiting for a watchdog reset.

Comment: @Clifford I share your frustration.  Sometimes I'll deliberately post an incomplete answer, just to get it posted, then complete it in a sequence of edits.  I have to weigh the confusion to the reader of seeing an incomplete answer, versus my own frustration in being unable to complete it at all if I don't do it that way.  (Theoretically that's bad behavior on my part: If I know the question's about to get closed, arguably I shouldn't be answering it at all.)

Comment: Also, "embedded C" is far too broad a question.  The capabilities of firmware support vary as wildly as the hardware.  Big difference between an 8-pin ATtiny and a dual-core ARM part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C language does not define runtime error handling. With respect to the language it results in undefined behaviour.  That does not mean that the execution environment cannot define specific behaviour or handling.

Divide-by-zero, invalid address, invalid alignment etc. are typically handled by the runtime environment as *exception handlers* (in cases where the processor supports any such exceptions).

In embedded systems, you are often responsible for providing suitable exception handlers, because the default runtime code will be generic and will not know what support a particular system has for presenting such errors.  If it is a COTS board with a vendor supplied BSP you may get more, and if you are running any kind of RTOS that is more than simple scheduling kernel, that may provide support.

For example on ARM Cortex-M using CMSIS, you typically have a startup_xxxx_.s file (where xxxx is the target device name) with for example:

```asm
HardFault_Handler PROC
                EXPORT  HardFault_Handler          [WEAK]
                B       .
                ENDP
MemManage_Handler PROC
                EXPORT  MemManage_Handler          [WEAK]
                B       .
                ENDP
BusFault_Handler PROC
                EXPORT  BusFault_Handler           [WEAK]
                B       .
                ENDP
UsageFault_Handler PROC
                EXPORT  UsageFault_Handler         [WEAK]
                B       .
                ENDP
```

Note they all have "weak-linkage" meaning that if you defined a handler (and on Cortex-M that can be a C function) with the same name, it will override the default.  So you might for example have:

```
void HardFault_Handler(void)
{
    volatile int stop = 1 ;

    // Emit status registers and stack dump (for example), 
    // or just a message.
    ...

    // If debugger is connected, halt program here
    if (CoreDebug->DHCSR & 1) {
        __breakpoint(0);
    }

    // infinite loop, allow debugger 
    // to force return by clearing `stop`.
    while( stop )
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C programming doesn't support runtime error checks